# php mysql update table using variables not working

Tags: php, mysql

i have data on one form which is echoed form a table, i want to use this data to update information in another table. whenever i hit the update button it show an error, "could not update data: query was empty", here is the update code, please help me out.

```
  <?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = '';

        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

        if(! $conn ) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $ItemId = $_POST['ItemId'];
        $Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];

       //$sql = "UPDATE stationery ". "SET Quantity = $Quantity ". "WHERE ItemId = $ItemId" ;
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE stationery set Quantity = ". $Quantity ." WHERE ItemId = '".$ItemId."'");
       //$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE stationery SET Quantity = ".mysql_real_escape_string($Quantity)." WHERE IltemId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($ItemId)."'");
        mysql_select_db('dbtest');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

        if(! $retval ) {
           die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "Updated data successfully\n";

        mysql_close($conn);
     }
  ?>
```

and this is the table where data is echoed from a mysql table

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dbtest", $con);

 $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM stationery");
echo "<table border = '1' style='margin-left:18px;margin-right:18px;'bgcolor='#CFC'>
  <tr><th bgcolor='#34495E' colspan='9'>
   <h1><font color='white' align='center'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspORDER OFFICE SUPPLIES</font></h1>
</th></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#CFC' font size='18'>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Item Id</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
</tr>";

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"ItemName\"  size=\"30\" value=\" ". $row ['ItemName'] . "\" readonly></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"ItemId\" value=\" ". $row ['ItemId'] . "\" readonly></td>";
   echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Quantity\" required></td>";
   echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" size=\"30\" style='background-color:#3366FF' value=\"Update  \"></td>";

 echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
  }
  echo "</table>";


  mysql_close($con);

 ?>
```

Comment: What is the error it showing ?

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead

Comment: the error is : Could not update data: Query was empty

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE stationery set Quantity = ". $Quantity ." WHERE ItemId = '".$ItemId."'");
```

To:

```
$sql = "UPDATE stationery set Quantity = '". $Quantity ."' WHERE ItemId = '".$ItemId."'";
```

Full Code:

```
<?php 
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$ItemId = $_POST['ItemId'];
$Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];

$sql = "UPDATE stationery set Quantity = '". $Quantity ."' WHERE ItemId = '".$ItemId."'";;

mysql_select_db('test');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {
   die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: the error is no longer there but still it does not update the data

Comment: What is the data type of `Quantity ` ?

Comment: quantity is an integer while itemid is varchar

Comment: Can you post your `table` structure here ?

Comment: when i run the SQL query describe stationery it gives me this message  Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available. the columns for the table are ItemName this is varchar its the unique key,ItemId varchar(primary key and Quantity int

Answer (score 0):

Use single-quotes for PHP Variables and back ticks for SQL-related names:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `stationery` set `Quantity` = '$Quantity' WHERE `ItemId` = '$ItemId'");
```